# Bad response from freeSSHd server

Tags: ssh

I'm using ssh client called Granados to connect to servers.
When I use CopSSH as ssh server, everything works fine, but when I use freeSSHd as ssh server I get strange response from server that contains something like that:

"[4;41H [4;49H [4;42H [4;49H [4;43H [4;49H [4;44H [4;49H [4;45H [4;49H
[4;46H [4;49H [4;47H [4;49H [4;48H [4;49H
[4;1HC:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>cat /proc/meminfot [4;52H [4;50H
[4;1HC"

Does anybody know what does this symbols means?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like telnet escape sequences sent by the shell. Most likely when you connect to the server, the shell is started automatically, and when you connect to CopSSH, different shell is started (which doesn't send such sequences).